# How do I use a jQuery Plugin in Typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack

I already have the types installed for e.g. datetimepicker (@types/jquery.ui.datetimepicker), but how do I go on from here?

Yarn suggests to install it via

> npm install --save jquery.ui.datetimepicker

but it fails with a 404 error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you mean `jquery-datetimepicker`?

Comment: How can I use jquery-datetimepicker with TS?

Comment: If you are not using any framework, you have to import `jquery` first, then `jquery-ui` and then `$` or `jQuery` is available in global scope.

Comment: I already have that working. But the method $(...).datetimepicker() is not available.